# "Bring to front" from user control

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I have user control (100x25) that contain DataGridView (100x700).
 Dimension in bracket.
When i drop control on form and set size do 100x25 rest of DataGridView are not displayed.
Is there any chance to force "bring to front on parent", so all content of user control will be displayed on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because the contents of the user control can not overflow the size of the user control. It's like asking if you can have a textbox be displayed that is bigger than the form it appears on - it makes no sense.

Comment: It truth. Question was only hypothetical.